# Como passar um Array para o AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

```
array (
  0 => 
  Pessoa::array (
      'nome' => 'Paulo',
      'idade' => 15,
    )


app.controller('meuCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
 $http.get('ajax/getPessoa.php').success(function(data){
 $scope.list = data;

...
```

*Eu não quero que os dados fiquem visíveis na getPessoa.php. Existe algum outra forma de passar meus dados(array) para o AngularJS de maneira que fique oculta?*

Comment: SIm, para que seus dados fiquem ocultos, voce precisa criptografá-los no PHP antes de passar-los para o cliente. Encontrei esse framework aqui que pode te ajudar nessa solução `http://www.jcryption.org/`

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa serializar a array como JSON, que é o que o Angular está esperando receber:

```
<?php
$dados = array (
    array (
        'nome' => 'Paulo',
        'idade' => 15,
    ),
    array (
        'nome' => 'João',
        'idade' => 20,
    )
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dados);
```

> Eu não quero que os dados fiquem visíveis na getPessoa.php.

Não sei se entendi direito essa parte, mas se você está querendo que se a pessoa digitar a URL desse arquivo no browser não apareça nada, não, não é possível. Se você impede o browser de enxergar os dados, o Angular também não poderá enxergá-los.